# Facebook iOS-SDK 3.8 show progress when uploading

Tags: ios, facebook, file-upload

This is just FRUSTRATING! (sorry for the rant, I'm somewhat furious right now)

I managed to make the new SDK upload videos to a user's timeline/video-folder. Whew!

But videos tend to be big. It's not like posting a status to the timeline which takes like a second. Uploading videos can take LONG!!!

All I need is a way to tell the user how much of his video has been uploaded so far. That shouldn't be that much of a problem, should it?

Apparently, it is. There's no delegate-method in the new SDK that provides this functionality.

The old SDK could be «hacked» by implementing some method (`- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite)`. But with the new SDK, this isn't possible anymore...

Did ANYONE find a solution to this? Showing the user just an activity indicator is definitely not user-friendly...